# NetworkManager dropping interface

Tags: linux, networking, centos-7

I am trying to determine why my management interface on a Cent7 box goes down after about an hour or so consistently. I have to bring a crash cart into our server room to `ifdown eno2 && ifup eno2` to bring the interface back online.  Has anyone seen this before? Here are the log entries that NetworkManager is showing at the time of the interface going down.

`journalctl -u NetworkManager` :

```
Aug 13 16:01:01 slc-serv-01 NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1565733661.6495] device (eno2): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'connection-removed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 13 16:01:01 slc-serv-01 NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1565733661.6502] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTING
Aug 13 16:01:01 slc-serv-01 NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1565733661.6609] device (eno2): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'connection-removed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 13 16:01:01 slc-serv-01 NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1565733661.6732] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
```

I will post more configuration settings tomorrow once I have access to the box again. Any ideas are greatly appreciated!!